# Extract pairs of two from list with for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have list of which I want to extract pairs of two consecutive numbers. The iterator should thus take two numbers and then skip and take the next pair:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Aim:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I wrote this little loop to do this...

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  print('pair:', a[i], a[i+1])
```

... but this does not skip after a found pair:

```
pair: 1 2
pair: 2 3
pair: 3 4
pair: 4 5
pair: 5 6
```

Where do I miss the 'skipping' part in the loop or how could I solve this?

Comment: Add the `step` argument for `range`: `for i in range(0, len(a), 2):`

Comment: Zip can do for you `zip(a[::2], a[1::2])`